# FFMPEG Live stream loop with overlay - Errors

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I'm trying to do a livestream with a video loop, sound from the desktop and an overlay image that updates when I replace the file and a text that also updates when a file is replace but I seem to be running into problems. Any help is most appreciated:

```
VID=lol.mp4
STREAM_KEY=rmeow
TEXT=current.txt
COLOR="0xFFFFFF"
BCOLOR="0x000000"

ffmpeg -re -f alsa -i hw:Loopback,1,0 -framerate 10 -f image2 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -filter_complex overlay -stream_loop -1 -i $VID \
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 1984k -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k -vf "scale=1280:-1,format=yuv420p" -g 20 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 \
-vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/slant.ttf:bordercolor=$BCOLOR: borderw=1: fontcolor=$COLOR:textfile=$TEXT:reload=1:y=10:x=5:fontsize=38" \
-f flv "rtmp://live.restream.io/live/$STREAM_KEY" \

2> log_stream.txt
```

Output:

```
Only '-vf drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/slant.ttf:bordercolor=0x000000: borderw=1: fontcolor=0xFFFFFF:textfile=current_song.txt:reload=1:y=10:x=5:fontsize=38' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
Filtergraph 'drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/slant.ttf:bordercolor=0x000000: borderw=1: fontcolor=0xFFFFFF:textfile=current_song.txt:reload=1:y=10:x=5:fontsize=38' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i $VID -f image2 -re -framerate 10 -stream_loop -1 -i image.jpg -f alsa -i hw:Loopback,1,0 -filter_complex "overlay,scale=1280:-2,drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/slant.ttf:bordercolor=$BCOLOR: borderw=1: fontcolor=$COLOR:textfile=$TEXT:reload=1:y=10:x=5:fontsize=38,format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 1984k -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k -g 20 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 \
-f flv "rtmp://live.restream.io/live/$STREAM_KEY"`

1. `-re` should be put in front of non-live inputs, such as files, but not mic or camera inputs.
2. All filtering should be performed in one filtergraph, as shown above. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description
3. For better handing of image update, use `stream_loop` instead of `loop` which can fail if the image is being updated at the same time as ffmpeg is reloading it.

Comment: thank you very much for fixing up a lot of issues! With this it looks like it still plays the video track rather than whats being played on the server, any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: I don't know "*whats being played on the server*". The command will play the local video with the image overlaid on top of the video and text drawn on top of that. What do you see?

Comment: The -f alsa -i hw:Loopback,1,0 has music being played from mpc/mpd but unless I use a muted version of -i $VID, -i $VID take priority. Is there a command to mute -i $VID so that -f alsa -i hw:Loopback plays instead?
I tried moving the order around to see if it changed priority but it didn't.

Comment: Add `-an` before `-i $VID`.